# Use number from list B to get previous number in list A by using python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a tools to remove reference in my ascii file. So to remove the reference file, I need to delete line start from "file -rdi" to "maya file name.mb";" for each reference. The ascii file is look like this.[image]
So currently I am using my way(not sure is it the best way) to get the the start and end, and delete it. Below is my script to achieve this. Please look into **def removeReference(self):** for my question.

```
    ### import module
    from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
    from cStringIO import StringIO
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as xml
    import pysideuic, itertools

    uifile = "A:/Tech/Scripting/VG/scripts/Layout/EditMayaFile.ui"

    def loadUiType(uiFile):
        parsed = xml.parse(uiFile)
        widget_class = parsed.find('widget').get('class')
        form_class = parsed.find('class').text

        with open(uiFile, 'r') as f:
            o = StringIO()
            frame = {}

            pysideuic.compileUi(f, o, indent=0)
            pyc = compile(o.getvalue(), '<string>', 'exec')
            exec pyc in frame

            # Fetch the base_class and form class based on their type in the xml from designer
            form_class = frame['Ui_%s' % form_class]
            base_class = getattr(QtGui, widget_class)
        return form_class, base_class

    form_class, base_class = loadUiType(uifile)

    class EMF(form_class, base_class):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super(EMF, self).__init__(parent)
            self.setupUi(self)
            self.setObjectName('EMF')   
            self.populateEp()
            self.comboBox_episode.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.populateShot)
            self.comboBox_shot.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.addReference)
            self.pushButton_removeReference.clicked.connect(self.removeReference)

        def populateEp(self):
            self.comboBox_episode.clear()
            self.epiList = sorted(os.listdir ("V:/VG_S01"))
            self.epiList = [i for i in self.epiList if len(i) == 4]
            self.comboBox_episode.addItems(self.epiList)            

        def populateShot(self):
            episode = self.comboBox_episode.itemText(self.comboBox_episode.currentIndex())
            self.comboBox_shot.clear()
            self.shotList = sorted(os.listdir("V:/VG_S01/"+episode+"/animation/scenes/lay"))
            self.shotList = [i for i in self.shotList if i.endswith("_lay.ma")]
            self.comboBox_shot.addItems(self.shotList)  

        def addReference(self):
            episode = self.comboBox_episode.itemText(self.comboBox_episode.currentIndex())
            shot = self.comboBox_shot.itemText(self.comboBox_shot.currentIndex())
            self.listWidget_reference.clear()
            readMayaFile = open("V:/VG_S01/"+episode+"/animation/scenes/lay/"+shot, 'r')
            lines = readMayaFile.read().splitlines() 
            start = [i for i, s in enumerate(lines) if '//Codeset:' in s]
            end = [i for i, s in enumerate(lines) if 'requires maya "2016";' in s]
            readMayaFile.close()
            for each in list(set(lines[start[0]+1:end[0]])):
                x = each.split()[-1]
                if x.endswith('.mb";'):
                    self.listWidget_reference.addItem(x)


        def removeReference(self):
            episode = self.comboBox_episode.itemText(self.comboBox_episode.currentIndex())
            self.comboBox_episode.itemText(self.comboBox_episode.currentIndex())
            shot = self.comboBox_shot.itemText(self.comboBox_shot.currentIndex())
            readMayaFile = open("V:/VG_S01/"+episode+"/animation/scenes/lay/"+shot, 'r')
            lines = readMayaFile.read().splitlines() 
            readMayaFile.close()
            start = [i for i, s in enumerate(lines) if 'file -rdi' in s]
            end = [i for i, s in enumerate(lines) if self.listWidget_reference.currentItem().text() in s]

    def main():
        global ui
        try:
            ui.close()
        except:
            pass
        ui = EMF()
        ui.show()

    if __name__=="__main__":
        main()
```

To simplify my question, I make a new code below.

```
a = [**4**, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, **28**, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50, 52, 54, 56, 59, 61, 63, 65, 68, 70, 72, **75**] 
b = [**5**, **29**, **78**]
c = []
```

I want to get previous number of item b in a and append to c.

Expect to get this:

```
c = [**4**, **28**, **75**]
```

Hopefully you are understand my question since I also confuse how to ask for this. Thank you!

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
that reproduces your problem. [i downvoted your question because](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) you do not show any effort you made.

Comment: hi @hiroprotagonist, thanks for your advise, I already update my question, hopefully it can help next people. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Python's [`bisect` library](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/bisect.html):

```
from bisect import bisect_left

a = [4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50, 52, 54, 56, 59, 61, 63, 65, 68, 70, 72, 75] 
b = [5, 29, 32, 78]

c = [a[bisect_left(a, i) - 1] for i in b]
#output
[4, 28, 30, 75]
```

Please not that for this procedure `min(b)` must be greater than `min(a)`.

Comment: If `a` is  always sorted and the problem exactly as described then this feels like the way to go

Comment: i agree: a sorted list in python should always be a trigger to go for `bisect`.

Comment: Good point, @Chris_Rands I was lured by the example into the assumption of a sorted list, but it is not explicitly stated.

Comment: Hi @MrT , well done bro, u are saving my life. The  answer is totally what I want. Thank you very much and wish you have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

You could use `min()` with a key function in a list comprehension:

```
>>> [min(a, key = lambda x: abs(x - y)) for y in b]
[4, 28, 75]
```

This get the closest value in `a` to each value in `b` (which wasn't *exactly* what you asked for, but might be what you *meant* or at least still useful).

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it by *merging* `a` and `b` in a `temp` list, sorting it, and getting the previous elemenents of the elements originally in `b`.

```
a = [4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50, 52, 54, 56, 59, 61, 63, 65, 68, 70, 72, 75] 
b = [5, 29, 78]

temp = sorted(a + b)
res = [temp[temp.index(x)-1] for x in b]
print(res)   # -> [4, 28, 75]
```

This does have some limitations, but you do not seem to consider them either.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution using a list comprehension:

```
 a = [4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32,
    34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50, 52, 54, 56, 59, 61, 63,
    65, 68, 70, 72, 75]
b = [5, 29, 78]  
c=[]
for num in b:
    a2 = [num2 for num2 in a if num2 <= num]
    c.append(max(a2))
print(c)
```