# Find the previous number in a list of float and integer

Tags: python

i have a list of float and integers like below

```
[2,4.635,9,18,27.548,36]
```

For a given input i want to find the previous number of that input in the list by comparing that number with the numbers in list
For example:
if i give `8.9` as input i should get `4.635` as the output, is there any builtin function for this

Comment: To do what you want to do will always take `O(n)` complexity. So you could just write a simple `for` loop to do that.

Comment: Look at the [bisect module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/bisect.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use number from list B to get previous number in list A by using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49149955/use-number-from-list-b-to-get-previous-number-in-list-a-by-using-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [bisect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) to find the insertion point of a value in a sorted list:

```
import bisect 
li=[2,4.635,9,18,27.548,36]

>>> li[bisect.bisect_left(li,8.9)-1]    
4.635
```

You could also just use a simple `for` loop and `zip` on a sorted list as well:

```
for lo,hi in zip(li,li[1:]):
    if lo< 8.9 <=hi:
        print lo 
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot remember any builtin method for this, but it is quite easy to implement:

```
def get_previous(l, query):
    return max([x for x in l if x<query])

query = 8.9
l = [2,4.635,9,18,27.548,36]
result = get_previous(l, query)
```

If the list is sorted, there could be better ways to achieve this (binary search), but you don't state that fact.